Proving a property on a system on nonlinear ODEs
I have the following system of first-order nonlinear ODEs
$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda' &= - Y \frac{2 \kappa \Lambda^2 \Omega }{\Xi} + \frac{\Lambda \Xi}{\Omega}  \\
\Phi' &= \Phi \frac{4(\kappa R + 1)\Lambda \Omega - \Xi^2}{2 \Omega \Xi} \\
\Omega' &= \Xi \\
\Xi' &= \frac{3 \Xi^2}{4 \Omega}+ \Lambda - \kappa \Lambda \Omega X \\
R' &= - Y \frac{4(\kappa R + 1)\Lambda \Omega - \Xi^2}{2 \Omega \Xi} - W \frac{\Xi}{\Omega} 
\end{align}
$$
Where  $W, X, Y$ are functions of the domain, but they are subject to the additional constraint
$$2 Y - X = R$$
So they can overall be written as two freely specifiable functions.
The computational domain is chosen to be $(t_F, t_I)$ with $t_I, t_F > 0$ and boundary conditions of interest:
$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda(t_I) &= 1 \\
\Phi(t_I) &= 1 \\
\Omega(t_I) &= t_I^2 \\
\Xi(t_I) &= 2 t_I \\
R(t_I) &= 0 
\end{align}
$$
I've noticed that it is not stable to begin the integration with $t_I < t_F$.  $\kappa$ is a small constant about $10^{-2}$, and I've done my numerical experiments with scipy.integrate.solve_ivf
Now to the Question:
After several experiments with different functions $W, X, Y$, I have noticed that any time the function $\Xi$ becomes negative/crosses zero, either $\Lambda$ or $\Phi$ must also become negative/cross zero.
I don't know how to prove this though. Qualitatively it is true that $\Xi'$ has a strong bias toward being positive due to the $\frac{3 \Xi^2}{4 \Omega}+ \Lambda$  terms which are always positive, and that whenever $\Xi$ gets close to zero, both $\Lambda', \Phi'$ will diverge unless both $Y$ and $R$ have special values that nullify those derivatives. I've tried to prove that whenever $Y, R$ have those special values, $X$ will not be inside the region where $\Xi'$ is negative, but I haven't succeeded

As $W,X,Y$ are given functions, after reductions I arrive at
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Lambda '=-\frac{2 \Lambda  \left(\Lambda  Y (2 \kappa  W-2 \kappa  X+3 \kappa  Y+2)-\Xi  X'+2 \Xi  Y'\right)}{\Xi  (2
W-Y)} \
\Xi '=\Lambda +\frac{\Lambda  \kappa  \Xi ^2 X (2 W-Y)}{4 \Lambda  Y (-\kappa  X+2 \kappa  Y+1)-2 \Xi  X'+4
\Xi  Y'}+\frac{6 \Lambda  Y (\kappa  X-2 \kappa  Y-1)+3 \Xi  X'-6 \Xi  Y'}{4 W-2 Y} \
\end{array}
$$
